# How to set absolute element height 100% og parent

Tags: css

I need to change height of absolute element to 100% of parent.
So what i need to do I tried many type of height with padding and line height

```css
div{
    height:300px
}
.arrow {
    position: absolute;
    /* left: 0; */
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 102;
    width: 100px;
    justify-content: center;background: linear-gradient(to left, 
    rgba(255, 0, 0, 0), rgba(22, 23, 25, 1));
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="arrow"> <img src="/path"/> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `position:relative` on parent div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set position relative in parents div:

```
div{
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
}
.arrow {
    position: absolute;
    /* left: 0; */
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 102;
    width: 100px;
    justify-content: center;background: linear-gradient(to left, 
    rgba(255, 0, 0, 0), rgba(22, 23, 25, 1));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Absolute elements go up the DOM tree and look for the next Element with a position (`relative`, or `absolute`) to position themselves.

So you `div` needs a `position: relative;` in order for the `.arrow` to use it for positioning and sizing.